# Apache Mod Rewrite with Periods in URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, period

Ok,

so I am using (or trying to use) two primary mod_rewrite rules, and they seem to be conflicting with one another

```
RewriteRule ^/?help$ index.php?page=help [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

If I get rid of the period ->. in the second rule, my help page is displayed, and I can display a user page as well, but when I add the period, my help page doesn't display, but instead (I think) gets processed as a user page.

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at something another user ran into here - [Apache / mod_rewrite / Periods messing with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077304/apache-mod-rewrite-periods-messing-with-pattern?rq=1) , and modified his rule, and it is working -

```
RewriteRule ^/?help$ index.php?page=help [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\.()+|_-]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Thankyou for the response.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are doing this in .htaccess mod_rewrite does not stop processing but instead does an internal redirect. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/286005/991314) for details.

You need to escape the period in your second rewrite rule. Period (or dot) will match any character if not escaped.

Fixed rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)$ /index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

**Edit 3:**

Based on your comments and own answer, here's an updated solution. The way `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}` works in Apache depends on the context you are in. You can also omit the `?` from the matching pattern.

```
RewriteRule ^/help$ /index.php?page=help [L]
# If you are inside <VirtualHost> context
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)$ /index.php?user=$1 [L]
# If you are inside <Directory> or .htaccesscontext
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)$ /index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Do bear in mind that this solution causes conflicts if there are users with the same name as any of the files or directories you have on your server.

Comment: I am trying to make ?page=help direct to /help, and ?user=user.name direct to /user.name (I should have posted that originally...sorry.).  Even escaping the period doesn't direct the help page properly.  It's being read as a user page. When I echo the $_GET['user'] variable of the help page, it says "index.php".   I tried the rewrite conditions also, but it gave me a 404.

Comment: Thanks for the response btw.

Comment: To clarify, my site url would be www.site.com/help, and php would process index.php?page=help internally.   It works, but when I try to add a "user" rule, it doesn't unless I exclude the period.

Comment: Reverted back to my original answer based on your comments. Tested to work with periods. Furthermore if you are within <VirtualHost> context and not .htaccess, and you want to avoid matching existing files as your own answer suggests, you need to modify the RewriteCond a bit.